# Slice a specific row out of pandas groupby dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need to slice a particular row out of a groupby dataframe using 2 columns titles (The image is provided).I need the output of "Age" for a given Gender and Country.

[Output of the groupby dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b47h1.png)

Comment: Please put code and data in the body of your post rather than putting up a screenshot https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Does my attempt help. If it doesnt, post your data not the image and we will help

Comment: Did it work or you need more help?

Answer (score 0):

Now that you didnt give data. Lets use free data from seaborn

Data

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
tips
```

Groupby to get similar result to yours

```
df=tips.groupby(['sex','time'])['tip'].sum().to_frame()
df
```

Several ways to slice multi index for row;

```
##Silce Male Dinner
df.loc['Male','Dinner',:]

##Silce Female Dinner and Lunch
df.loc['Female',:]

#slice(None) to select all the contents of that level.
df.loc[(slice(None),'Lunch'),:]
```

Comment: df_GC = df.groupby(['GenderSelect', 'Country'])
df_GC.describe()
df_GC.loc['Male','United States',:].     but the error I get this time is Cannot access callable attribute 'loc' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Comment: Please provide me with a sample of your data. I worked of a generic dataset and cant figure out how to relate what you are doing to the answer I provided. Happy to help